# PHP Add User to Favorites System?

Tags: php, mysql, favorites

i'll try be as clear as possible. I'm brand new to php and mysql so i'm sorry in advance because i'm probably a long way off accomplishing this, but i'm trying to allow users of mys site click a favorite button on another users profile and have this set the user to their favorites in mysql table.

So far i've designed a basic table like so:

```
    ID                 |             User_ID             |       Favorite_ID

ID Auto Incs by 1            Person Favouring User            User being favoured
```

I'm just trying to make it so that once the favorite button is pressed on the user's profile this a href's to favorite.php where this echo's the profile_id and the session id and stores the two in the table.

That should then allow me to set a query which pulls all the favorite id's WHERE the user_id is 'x'.

Please can someone show me what i'd need to do. thank you.

Here's my button link:

```
<a href="favorite.php?to=<?php echo "$profile_id"; ?>">+ Favorite</a>
```

Here's my code i'm using:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
  <?php 

// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    require('includes/_config/connection.php');
// LOAD FUNCTIONS
    require('includes/functions.php');
// GET IP ADDRESS
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

?>
  <?php require_once("includes/sessionframe.php"); 
?>

  <?php

    confirm_logged_in();

    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];  
}

?> 
  <?php 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_favorites (id, user_id, favorite_id) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$user_to_id."');";
            mysql_query($sql, $connection);

            echo "<div class=\"infobox2\">User has been added to your favorites.</div>";
            header('Location: http://localhost/ptb1/profile.php');      
?>
<?php ob_end_flush() ?>
```

Comment: What is your question? Is it not working? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Change your button link

```
<a href="favorite.php?to=<?php echo "$profile_id"; ?>">+ Favorite</a>
```

To this

```
<a href="favorite.php?to=<?php echo $profile_id; ?>">+ Favorite</a>
```